# How to index 0-d array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

This may be a well-known question stored in some FAQ but i can't google the solution. I'm trying to write a scalar function of scalar argument but allowing for ndarray argument. The function should check its argument for domain correctness because domain violation may cause an exception. This example demonstrates what I tried to do:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    y[x>0.0] = 1.0/x
    return y

print f(1.0)
```

On assigning `y[x>0.0]=...` python says `0-d arrays can't be indexed`.
What's the right way to solve this execution?

Comment: Tricky ;). Use `y[np.asarray(x>0.0)] = ...` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks you seberg! I don't knw why but it works!

Comment: Comes down to difference between scalar arrays and (array-)scalars... And boolean indexing is only triggered with boolean *array*s at this time at least.

Comment: @seberg please consider posting your suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine in NumPy >= 1.9 (not released as of writing this). On previous versions you can work around by an extra `np.asarray` call:

```
x[np.asarray(x > 0)] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you call `f([1.0])` instead?

Otherwise you can do:

```
x = np.asarray(x)
if x.ndim == 0:
    x = x[..., None]
```

Comment: Not me call it but scipy.integration.quad does. Anyway, seberg gave the trick.