# Why does python think my array is 0-d? (TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, sorting

I'm aware that this may have been answered before but **please check that other answers are relevant to this instance!**

I'm writing an array to a file as a string so that it can be stored when my script isn't running and be accessed again easily when run. When I then read this string out of the file again it is automatically read as a string.

I can fix this with a for loop that iterates through the saved string and appends each entry to an empty array, but that seems like overkill - is it? Is there a better way to read a string and convert it to an array?

So... something like this runs the first time in order to generate an array and write it to a file as a string:

```
the_file = open('.the_file.txt', 'w')
the_array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
the_file.write(str(the_array))
the_file.close()
```

The next time the code is run a different section of code gets run that is something like this:

```
the_file = open('.the_file.txt', 'r')
the_array = the_file.read()
the_file.close()
```

If I print the the_array variable and its type at this point I get:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
<type 'str'>
```

So I follow the advice given in [this similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560993/how-to-index-0-d-array-in-python) and do:

```
the_array = np.asarray(the_array)
```

...and then print the the_array variable and its type at this point to check that this has worked, to get:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

But now when I run the rest of my code I get the error:

```
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

Traced back to this part of my code:

```
the_array = sorted(the_array, reverse=True)
```

Can anyone help me out here; why does python think that my array is 0-d?

Comment: `np.asarray` doesn't parse strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_array = np.asarray(the_array)` is creating an array with one element in it: your string `"[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]"`. Rather than read your file in, if you `import json` and replace `the_array = the_file.read()` with `the_array = json.load(the_file)`, you'll get a list instead and can easily convert it to a numpy array.